# How can I use robocopy to exclude files with multiple periods using wildcards?

Tags: powershell, robocopy

I have multiple config files that I need to copy to a destination directory. Some of these files have multiple extensions like the following:

> web.config.env1
>
> web.config.env2
>
> web.config.something

I also have files that just simply end in ".config". I'd like to use Robocopy to copy all files in a directory plus the ".config" files while excluding any ".config.*" files.

So I tried the following in powershell:

```
robocopy $SourceDir $DestinationDir "*.*" /L /XF "*.config.*"
```

However, if I try to exclude anything matching "*.config.*" it also excludes all configuration files that end with only with "*.config". How should I go about excluding the config files with additional extensions while copying all others?

Comment: perhaps this belongs on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Instead of `*.config.*`, could you use `*.config.env*`?

Comment: @David I should have been more clear. "env" isn't the actually extension, just a placeholder. The actual extensions have no words in common.